# Getting percentage of breaching SLA tickets

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have table where I have data of zendesk tickets with all the SLA details.

For instance, with this table I can write a query like below to see where a particular service ticket has breached the SLA or not.

`case when m.reply_time_in_minutes.[calendar] > 120 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as 'fr_sla_breach'`

If I want to get a percentage of breach for each person, how can I approach this.

I am not developer, but If you guys show some way to think I can develop it.

The O/P of the data will look like below:

| person | ticket id | fr_sla_breach |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | 1234 | yes |
| Person B | 3453 | no |

This is the result I am able to get. But If I want to get the below O/P , how can i go about it.

| person | fr_sla_breach_percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | 50% |

I can able to see for a particualr person how many were breaching SLA and how many are not. But If I want to figure out the percentage, not sure how to approach it.

**Complete Query:**

```
SELECT assignee_name,
       'https://hevodata.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/'|| t.id AS URL,
                                                       t.created_at,
                                                       m.solved_at,
                                                       m.initially_assigned_at,
                                                       CASE
                                                           WHEN m.reply_time_in_minutes.[calendar] > 120 THEN 'Yes'
                                                           ELSE 'No'
                                                       END AS "fr_sla_breach"
FROM tickets t
JOIN ticket_metrics m ON t.id = m.ticket_id
WHERE date(t.created_at) BETWEEN 'MM/DD/YYYY' AND 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  AND t.assignee_name LIKE ('XXX%')
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) (Red Hat 3.4), Redshift 1.0.

Comment: Will only 'yes' ones be accepted?

Comment: Yes. can be accepted as breach